# Slow Downloads Using MS Access

Tags: ms-access, download, vba, ms-office

I have a sub that opens excel, creates a connection to my google sheet, then uses an insert statement to add the data to my Access database.
This works but is incredibly slow (takes ~30sec to get 6 records)

```
Private Sub ImportFromGoogleSheet()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Dim appXL As Object 'Excel.Application
Dim wbk As Object 'Excel.Workbook
Dim wst As Object 'Excel.Worksheet
Dim Timer As Integer

Set appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
appXL.Visible = True 'If you want to see the excel sheet - enable this row (good for debugging)
Set wbk = appXL.Workbooks.Add
Set wst = wbk.Worksheets(1)

With wst
    .QueryTables.Add Connection:= _
    "URL;https://connection to site here ", Destination:=.Range("$A$1")
    .Name = "Worksheet1"

    .QueryTables(1).Refresh
End With

'Wait for google-doc data to be downloaded.
Timer = 0
Do While Left(wst.cells(1, 1), 12) = "ExternalData" And Timer < 40
    'Sleep 250 ' Wait 0.25 sec before re-checking data
    'Timer = Timer + 1
Loop

Dim rownum As Integer
rownum = 4
wst.cells(rownum, 2).Select
Do While (wst.cells(rownum, 2).Value <> "")
    Dim sqlStr As String
    Dim ts, dol As Date
    Dim sn, lt As String
    Dim nod As Integer
    ts = wst.cells(rownum, 2).Value
    dol = wst.cells(rownum, 5).Value
    sn = wst.cells(rownum, 3).Value
    lt = wst.cells(rownum, 4).Value
    nod = wst.cells(rownum, 6).Value

    sqlStr = "INSERT INTO table VALUES"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL sqlStr
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    rownum = rownum + 1
Loop

wbk.Close SaveChanges:=False 'Don't save excel sheet
appXL.Quit
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
If (Err.Number = 3022) Then
    Debug.Print "Record Already Exists"
    Resume
End If
Debug.Print Err.Description & Err.Number

wbk.Close SaveChanges:=False 'Don't save excel sheet
appXL.Quit
End Sub
```

I have tried removing the first while loop but then nothing is imported

Is there something in the code slowing it down or is this just a slow process?

*I know this might be appropriate for code review but i'm more interested in why its slow than if its bad code

**Edit to add debugging output and new while

```
Debug.Print "before wait while " & Now
'Wait for google-doc data to be downloaded.
lTimer = 0
Do While Left(wst.cells(1, 1), 12) = "ExternalData" And lTimer < 40
    Debug.Print "Wait loop " & lTimer 
    Debug.Print "during wait while " & Now
    Sleep 250 ' Wait 0.25 sec before re-checking data
    DoEvents
    lTimer = lTimer + 1
Loop

Debug.Print "after wait while" & Now
```

code end

```
start time 18/07/2017 9:06:58 a.m.
before connect 18/07/2017 9:06:58 a.m.
before wait while 18/07/2017 9:07:00 a.m.
Wait loop 0
during wait while 18/07/2017 9:07:00 a.m.
Wait loop 1
during wait while 18/07/2017 9:07:00 a.m.
Wait loop 2
during wait while 18/07/2017 9:07:01 a.m.
Wait loop 3
during wait while 18/07/2017 9:07:01 a.m.
Wait loop 4
during wait while 18/07/2017 9:07:01 a.m.
Wait loop 5
during wait while 18/07/2017 9:07:01 a.m.
Wait loop 6
during wait while 18/07/2017 9:07:02 a.m.
Wait loop 7
during wait while 18/07/2017 9:07:02 a.m.
Wait loop 8
during wait while 18/07/2017 9:07:02 a.m.
Wait loop 9
during wait while 18/07/2017 9:07:02 a.m.
Wait loop 10
during wait while 18/07/2017 9:07:03 a.m.
Wait loop 11
during wait while 18/07/2017 9:07:03 a.m.
after wait while 18/07/2017 9:07:28 a.m.
```

Comment: Have you tried timing the different sections?  How long does it take to complete the download vs. perform the insert?

Comment: Not exactly but i put a breakpoint before the insert loop and virtually all of the wait happened before that breakpoint

Comment: So it seems like the issue is the web fetch from Google: hard to say how you could speed that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found another problem where only 100 records were being downloaded and the solution for that fixed the speed problem as well.

I found the solution [here](https://community.qlik.com/thread/160989).

It says that you need to change the format of the link from
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/YOURSPREADSHEET/edit?usp=sharing
to
https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=&key=YOURSPREADSHEET&gid=1

Which changes it from an editable view to a more basic view

Answer (score 0):

Use `Debug.Print` to see which parts actually take so long. [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

`Timer` is a function in Access, don't use it as variable name.

You waiting loop must have a `Sleep` call and a `DoEvents` call to avoid hogging your CPU.

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" Alias "Sleep" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

'Wait for google-doc data to be downloaded.
lTimer = 0
Do While Left(wst.cells(1, 1), 12) = "ExternalData" And lTimer < 40
    Debug.Print "Wait loop " & lTimer    ' Ctrl+g shows output
    Sleep 250 ' Wait 0.25 sec before re-checking data
    DoEvents
    lTimer = lTimer + 1
Loop
```

If this doesn't help, you'll probably have to live with it.